# New to Java, why doesn't this code work? i++ is 'dead code', and the function does not return a variable of desired type; even though it does

Tags: java

I am making a little program in Java that makes a program that acts like a "library", only with video games. In the program you shoud be able to add, delete and edit games; you shoud also be able to list off all the games in the "library".

To be able to delete and edit games, I have decided to implement a function that will return a list of all the elements in the list that matches the query String that I give it, and then the user will have to choose between a numbered list of all the returned results.

This is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<GameStorage> findElement(ArrayList<GameStorage> gameList, String query) {
    ArrayList<GameStorage> temp = new ArrayList<GameStorage>();
    for(int i = 0; i < gameList.size(); i++) {
        if(gameList.get(i).getName().contains(query)) {
            temp.add(gameList.get(i));
        }
    return temp;
    }
}
```

I initialize an empty GameStorage ArrayList, and use this to store all the desired elements and then return it. However, this does not work at all and Eclipse says that the `i++` part is supposedly 'dead code' (and this supposedly means that the code never is reached), the function also says that I do not return a result of the desired type `ArrayList<GameStorage>`, even though I do. I don't know what I've done wrong.

Could someone perhaps enlighten me?

Comment: Why do you return on the first iteration of the loop? The reason why it says dead code is because it will never reach  the increment stage of the for loop.

Comment: Take the `return` out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return` should be **after** your loop body, not the last statement. Because it is the last statement `i++` is never reached. Change it like

```
for(int i = 0; i < gameList.size(); i++) {
    if(gameList.get(i).getName().contains(query)) {
        temp.add(gameList.get(i));
    }
}
return temp;
```

You could also use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
for (GameStorage gs : gameList) {
    if (gs.getName().contains(query)) {
        temp.add(gs);
    }
}
return temp;
```

And in Java 8+ you might implement the entire method<sup>**1**</sup> with a `filter` and [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

```
public static List<GameStorage> findElement(List<GameStorage> gameList, String query) {
    return gameList.stream().filter(x -> x.getName().contains(query))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

<sup>**1**<sub>And I would prefer to program to the `List` interface.</sub></sup>

Comment: Oh, haha, I feel so stupid right now. Thanks for helping me!
I didn't know Java had ForEach-loop, that's cool to know! :D

Answer (score 3):

You can make your code shorter with java 8+ lambda's example below

```
gameList.forEach((k)->{
    if(k.getName().contains(query)){
        temp.add(k)
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing an expression to lambda only to wrap it in `forEach` method is not as much shorter but slower and you cannot assign to local variables anymore. Yeah I know, Java 8 lambdas are great but don't overuse them.

Comment: If you're going all lambda, might as well use streams: `return gameList.filter(k -> k.getName().contains(query)).collect(toList());`